# Can i submit paper that result's not expected?

Tags: research-process, paper-submission, negative-results

my results were not expected which was control was lower than treatment and it's supposed to be lower than control according to other papers.
I used the data and finished the paper and was trying to submit but my prof said I couldn't use this data because it's not the expected results and it was my error while doing the experiment?

Comment: Your job is to prove your Prof wrong, and provide reasons.   The reasons are your contributions.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus, "*Your job is to prove your Prof wrong*" Their job is to find the truth.  Maybe the professor is right and the OP did the experiment incorrectly.

Comment: Did your professor say "that result cannot be true, so you must have made an error", or did (s)he point out a specific error you made that caused your result. In the former case your professor is plain wrong. In the latter case the professor may be right.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, some of the most important papers in the past century were on results that were not expected (e.g. [Michelson-Morley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment) paper, the papers that discovered dark energy).

But such a paper needs to be quite detailed. You need to examine all the possible reasons that might have affected your results, e.g. systemic bias, potential sources of error, do careful estimates of error margins, and so on. If you can eliminate every possible source of error you can think of, and if you can be sure that the result really is robust, then it's something you can publish.

It sounds like your professor doesn't think you've reached that point, so you have work to do and submitting the paper now is likely premature.